# How to get IContentLoader instance using constructor injection

Tags: episerver

I Have this code

```
var loader = EPiServer.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentLoader>();
```

I want to get the instance of IContentLoader using constructor injection.

Comment: Have you tried adding a constructor argument of type `IContentLoader`? Which version of Episerver are you running? Which version of the EPiServer.ServiceLocation.StructureMap package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on a recent Episerver version (NuGet package `EPiServer.ServiceLocation.StructureMap` > 2.0), you should be able to simply:

```
public MyPageController(IContentLoader contentLoader)
{
   // Do something with contentLoader
}
```

Comment: I believe you still need to register the `DependencyResolver` or did I miss something? :)